# Where check log why VM doesn't running for jconsole with custom jar?

Tags: java, logging, jar, jconsole

I try run jconsole with jar that contains my classes like:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin"
set console="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\jconsole.jar"
set tools="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\tools.jar"
set customjar="C:\custom.jar"
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%console%:%tools%:%customjar%
```

But nothing happens - jconsole doesn't start! Where to check what error happens?
BTW simple jconsole - startds, all paths are checked and correct.
Thanks.

Comment: As I remember you should use ';' in classpath under Windows instead of ':' (Unix-style)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember you should use ';' in classpath under Windows instead of ':' (Unix-style)