# jconsole does not start with arguments (command line)

Tags: weblogic, jconsole

I'm trying to start jconsole to monitor Weblogic beans.

I'm following this website, but changed the command to Windows format.

https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/managing_weblogic_servers_with

Command:

```
jconsole 
-J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar;%WL_HOME%/server/lib/wljmxclient.jar 
-J-Djmx.remote.protocol.provider.pkgs=weblogic.management.remote 
-J-Dcom.sun.tools.jconsole.mbeans.keyPropertyList=type,Type,j2eeType,name,Name -debug
```

Values of the environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
WL_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3
```

When I run that command, jconsole never starts. When I run just "jconsole", the jconsole window pops up.

I saw this question of someone who also had trouble running jconsole, but  my path looks right:
[Where check log why VM doesn't running for jconsole with custom jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086072/where-check-log-why-vm-doesnt-running-for-jconsole-with-custom-jar)

I also tried running just `jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar` , but it still did not start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need quotes around your classpath, likely because of the space in `Program Files`. For instance this works for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\jconsole" -J-Djava.class.path="%JAVA_HOME%/lib/jconsole.jar"
```